# Create a Bat file after finish installation on inno setup

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

It works well! The problem is that when creating the bat it does not create the path where it was created.

This is my current code:

```
[Code]
function CreateBatch(): boolean;
var
  fileName : string;
  lines : TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := true;
  fileName := ExpandConstant('{pf}\{#MyAppName}\batch.bat');
  SetArrayLength(lines, 2);
  lines[0] := '{pf}\{#MyAppName}\soft21\launcher.exe" -g "{pf}\{#MyAppName}\soft\code\Turbo.rpx';
  lines[2] := 'exit';
  Result := SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,true);
  exit;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if  CurStep=ssPostInstall then
    begin
         CreateBatch();
    end
```

What I need is for the bat to be created with the current location where it was created with the following code line.

It should look like this, example:

"C:\Program Files\soft21\launcher.exe" -g "C:\Program Files\soft12\code\Turbo.rpx"

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't `ExpandConstant` for `lines[0]`?

Comment: thanks working now! but i have another problem look at it below in the other answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `ExpandConstant` value for `lines[0]`.

Remember about proper quotations.

If you don't want to append your batch every time you install your application, do not use `true` for [`SaveStringsToFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_savestringstofile.htm).

```pascal
[Code]
function CreateBatch(): boolean;
var
  fileName : string;
  lines : TArrayOfString;
begin
    //test for directory
    if not DirExists(ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}')) then begin
        CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}'));
    end;
    //test for dir end
  fileName := ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}\batch.bat');
  SetArrayLength(lines, 2);
  lines[0] := ExpandConstant('"{pf}\{#MyAppName}\soft21\launcher.exe" -g "{pf}\{#MyAppName}\soft\code\Turbo.rpx"');
  lines[1] := 'exit';
  Result := SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,true);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if  CurStep=ssPostInstall then
    begin
         CreateBatch();
    end
end;
```

Comment: its working now! but i have a new problem is when I select another path that is not program files, the bat is not created

Comment: As `SaveStringsToFile` does not create Directories. In such case you'd have to check `DirExists` and if not, then create such Dir. Example added.